# RestTemplate response deserialization for polymorphic field without type field

Tags: java, jackson, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate to send requests to an API.

I have two different objects in the API, Person and Organization, which are almost the same. Once creating one of them, the response I get from the API is the actual object.

The response object looks like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {
    private boolean success;
    private ResponseData data;
}
```

where "data" can be Organization or Person ( both extends ResponseData ).

For example:

```
public class ResponseData {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
public class Person extends ResponseData {
    private int companyId;
    private int ownerId;
}
```

```
public class Organization extends ResponseData {
   private String title;
}
```

And I want to use RestTemplate to create an Organization, something like this ( if possible ):

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, method, new HttpEntity<>(body, headers), Response.class)
```

And that the result ( the Organization object ) will be mapped into the "data" field.

Is there a way to use RestTemplate in a way that will parse the response, specifically the data field into Organization or Person according to the request without creating a wrapper object that contains the "success" field and Person/Organization data field?

Note that the response object doesn't contain any "type" field or anything that mention the type of the object, so I'm not sure I can use @JsonTypeInfo.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] where you're calling the rest template?

Comment: Edited my question, hope it is more clear now, Thanks.